# Flask routing does not give desired results, URL not getting appended for some instance

Tags: python, html, flask

I am building a web-app using flask where I am trying to route some URLs

I have three routes with me
a) "/"
b) "/teacher"
c) "/student"

The routing works fine for "/" and"/student" The URL gets appended after clicking the submit button for student and"/student" gets appended in URL but on clicking the button associated with "/teacher" the URL doesn't gets appended and "/" page keeps on loading up.

Please help me out here and tell me what wrong I am doing

My Python code:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def select():
    return render_template("select.html")

@app.route('/teacher', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    return render_template("index_teacher.html", title="Faculty login")


@app.route('/student', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index1():
    return render_template("index_student.html", title="Student login")
```

Part of my html code from select.html:

```
<form action="/teacher" method = "post">
    <input type="submit" class="submit" value="Login as Teacher">
</form>
<br>

<form action="/student" method="post">
    <input type="submit" class ="submit" value="Login as Student">
</form>
```

One more thing about the code, when I add a text box above the first submit button, both the button starts working and give desired results.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think you have just a little typo in the html. The input tag of teacher didn't close `>`.

```
<form action="/teacher" method = "post">
    <input type="submit" class="submit" value="Login as Teacher">
</form>
<br>

<form action="/student" method="post">
    <input type="submit" class ="submit" value="Login as Student">
</form>
```

EDIT:
In the case that the question was copied incorrectly, I don't know what should be wrong with your code. For me your sample code works just fine. So from my experience with flask and html forms the most common errors I made are the following, maybe it's one of them (the list may serve other too, so I will also add points that do not make sense for your case):

- method name of two routes collide (e.g. both '/' and '/teacher' are assigned to function `index`, but that should give an error when starting the server, so not really possible)
- an html tag is not closed properly, so the form in question is not parsed as a valid form (that was my guess with above answer, also makes sense with the text box, which may close the corrupt tag => in html an open tag is closed by the first following closing tag)
- typo in the form action attribute (check the network tab in your browsers developer tools, maybe you get an error response to something like "taecher", which results in a redirect to "/", again not really plausible with the fact that it suddenly works when you add the text box)
- typo in the route or the returned template (again not plausible with explained behavior with the added text box)

That's all I can think of at the moment. I hope it helps with the search. if you could add more of your html code, maybe I find something suspicious.

Comment: It was a mistake that happened while posting question, I've edited the question,